# How to store the paths of files and return one JSON array after processing each file

Tags: schema

I have a scenario where I have to store JSON files in the following format, Ex: MP4_AES.json

```
    {
        "title":"MP4 test content without ads",
        "description":"MP4 test content without ads",
        "isLive":false,
        "content":[  
            {  
                "format":"MP4",
                "url":"http://urlToTheVideo.mp4"
            }
        ]
        "tags":[VOD, AES,.... .., LBA, TRICKPLAY]
    }
```

The files are stored in a filesystem like:
/path/to/MP4_AES.json
/path/to/HLS_AES.json
/path/to/HLS_LBA.json
/path/to/HLS_TRICKPLAY.json

Depending on the tags user choose, for an assumption let's say the user chooses AES and VOD, I want to return a JSON with an array which includes data from all files which have the respective tags:

```
   ["entries":[
    {
        "title":"MP4 test content without ads",
        "description":"MP4 test content without ads",
        "isLive":false,
        "content":[  
            {  
                "format":"MP4",
                "url":"http://urlToTheVideo.mp4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title":"HLS test content without ads",
        "description":"HLS test content without ads",
        "isLive":false,
        "content":[  
            {  
                "format":"HLS",
                "url":"http://urlToTheVideo.m3u8"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
   ]
```

tags property being excluded. How can I structure my database to store paths to respective files

If Some Edits are required please let me know. Please let me know if more appropriate tags can be added, so the people can find the question and answer it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be related to database administration, SQL, or schemas.

Comment: @mustaccio, thank you, but it would be really helpful so as to what tags can I add, and to which stackoverflow forum would be most appropriate.

Comment: I'm not even sure which SO site might be appropriate, because it's not clear what your problem is. What "database" are you talking about? What issues exactly do you have "structuring" that database to store file paths? A file system is a database of sorts, and it's perfectly suited to store paths, for example.

Comment: Voting to retain - this is about data storage and querying, which is this site's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 has [built in JSON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx) manipulation as does [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246) and [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).

Many NoSQL products support JSON structured data, with selection and transformation functions built-in.

There is no standard language or API, however. Each product handles the desired process differently.